# In WPF, how do I update the object that my custom property is bound to?

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a custom property that works perfectly, except when it's bound to an object.

The reason is that once the following code is executed:

```
base.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
```

... then my control is no longer *bound*. I know this because calling:

```
base.GetBindingExpression(ValueProperty);
```

... returns the binding object perfectly - **UNTIL** I call base.SetValue. So my question is, how do I pass the new "value" on to the object that I'm bound to?

EDIT: Here's the code...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ValueProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register("Value", typeof(decimal?), typeof(NumericTextBox));

public decimal? Value
{
    get
    {
        return (decimal?)base.GetValue(ValueProperty);
    }
    set
    {
        base.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's simple, boilerplate, "Microsoft sample" code.

EDIT 2: Here's the code for the binding...

```
// Apparently, not showing this line of code here has some people confused...
this.DataContext = new SomeClassWithAPropertyCalledNumericValue();

<my:NumericTextBox Value="{Binding NumericValue}" />
```

Again... simple.

Comment: Can you show us the code of (a) your custom property and (b) the binding?

Comment: Is the answer as simple as making your binding TwoWay and implementing property change notification?

Comment: Dependency properties have built-in change notification...

Comment: Need to see the rest of your code. Specifically, where is "NumericValue?" And why do you have a private _value member variable? Are you using that anywhere? I just constructed an example using only the code you have posted, and the binding works fine and is never cleared.

Comment: Check the output window if you see any Binding errors. Dep Properties work :) Microsoft told us so.

Comment: The binding "works" just fine... if I put break points in the "set" and "get" methods, I SEE THE CODE FIRING... but, as I've stated, once 'base.SetValue' happens, **then** it never fires again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think

```
base.SetCurrentValue(ValueProperty, value);
```

is what you're looking for

> **Summary**:
>   Sets the value of a dependency property without changing its value source.

Comment: Amazing! - I've changed my answer to yours instead of my own... I will be removing that extension method I made from my project soon. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

I've found the answer, and the fact that no one else has said this just shows that very few people are making their own custom controls...

1) If you just call "base.SetValue", you **WILL** destroy any binding applied to your custom property - simple as that.

2) What you have to do is determine if you are bound, if so, update the target **manually yourself** (really Microsoft?) - and if you're not bound, *then* you can call base.SetValue.

Here's the helper method I had to make:

```
private void SetValueOrBinding(decimal? value)
{
    var bindingExpression = this.GetBindingExpression(ValueProperty);

    if (bindingExpression == null)
    {
        base.SetValue(ValueProperty, value);
    }
    else
    {
        var target = bindingExpression.DataItem;

        var propertyInfo = target.GetType().GetProperty(bindingExpression.ParentBinding.Path.Path);

        propertyInfo.SetValue(target, value, null);
    }
}
```

Can you say extension method anyone?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to post more code.  You're binding to "NumericValue" in XAML which I don't see in your C# code.

As a wild guess, though, if you binding is in fact correct, you may need to move off the textbox in order to see the change (assuming you haven't tested it that way), or make your binding look like this to change with the property change:

```
{Binding NumericValue, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're binding to NumericValue, but you're not showing us NumericValue.  Based purely on the code above, your binding should be something along the lines of:

```
<my:NumericTextBox Text="{Binding Value}" />
```

If you really are meaning to bind "Value" to "NumericValue" then you're going to have to show us the DependencyProperty for NumericValue.

Comment: NumericTextBox is my own custom class... it doesn't have a "Text" property, it has a "Value" property. I'm binding my custom class's "Value" property to a decimal called NumericValue which is part of the datacontext that is attached.

Comment: And is NumericValue a DependencyProperty?